# How can I convert this C into MIPS?

Tags: c, mips, palindrome

```
int Reverse(int num)
{
    int remainder = 0;
    int rev = 0;
    while ( num != 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 10;
        num = num /10;
        rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
    }
    return rev;
}

void Palindrome()
{
    int num;
        cin >> num;
        Reverse(num);
        cout << num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if ( num != Reverse(num))
            {
                num = num + Reverse(num);
                cout << " " << num;
            }
            if ( num == Reverse(num))
            {
                 cout << " ";
            }
        }
 }
```

My biggest issue is the loops. The actual math isn't difficult, but I can't figure out how to set up loops, especially the if loops inside of the for loop.

I wrote this to take in an integer, then print out up to ten times, different integers
adding the integer backwards to itself, repeatedly checking to see if it is a palindrome.

The main program is already written in MIPS, as well as the rev function. I just don't
understand how I would go about doing the Palindrome procedure.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

I have tried this:

first I do the loop that will go on for 10 times.

Then I call the rev function in the palindrome procedure

```
jal rev                     # call rev function

la $a0, spaces              # display the number
bne $a0, $v0, then          # if num isnt equal to rev
add $a0, $a0, $t1           # num = num + reverse(num)
la spaces, $a0              # display the added number each time
beq $a0, $v0, then          # if num IS equal to rev

// display spaces instead??
```

I know it must be terribly wrong but this is my first time doing this.

Comment: Can you just compile it with gcc or something? Set the architecture as MIPS and go for it, unless you need to do some kind of hand optimization or something special?

Comment: Im very new with gcc and i have looked into it before and everything I attempt, I get "permission denied". I think my best bet is to write it out myself

Comment: A better bet could be LCC <http://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler>, it's a _lot_ easier to install (and generates MIPS code by default). But that is probably cheating in the MIPS assembler homework ;-)

Comment: There's a wikibook on MIPS assembly with the branch instructions you need to model `if`: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Control_Flow_Instructions#Branch_Instructions

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change the rev function but I had to change the Palindrome procedure to compile the C to MIPS. I can't compile `cin` or `cout`(aren't those C++?) so `cin` and `cout`are commented out.

```
int Reverse(int num)
{
    int remainder = 0;
    int rev = 0;
    while ( num != 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 10;
        num = num /10;
        rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
    }
    return rev;
}

void Palindrome()
{
    int num = 0;
    int i; 
        //cin >> num;
    Reverse(num);
        //cout << num;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if ( num != Reverse(num))
            {
                num = num + Reverse(num);
                //cout << " " << num;
            }
            if ( num == Reverse(num))
            {
                 //cout << " ";
            }
        }
 }

int main ( int argc , char * argv [] )
{
   return 0;
}




 # -G value = 8, Cpu = 3000, ISA = 1
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  Reverse
    .ent    Reverse
Reverse:
    .frame  $fp,16,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 1/0, args= 0, extra= 0
    .mask   0x40000000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,16
    sw  $fp,8($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,16($fp)
    sw  $0,0($fp)
    sw  $0,4($fp)
$L2:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    bne $2,$0,$L4
    j   $L3
$L4:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    li  $3,1717960704           # 0x66660000
    ori $3,$3,0x6667
    mult    $2,$3
    mfhi    $6
    sra $3,$6,2
    sra $4,$2,31
    subu    $3,$3,$4
    move    $5,$3
    sll $4,$5,2
    addu    $4,$4,$3
    sll $3,$4,1
    subu    $2,$2,$3
    sw  $2,0($fp)
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    li  $3,1717960704           # 0x66660000
    ori $3,$3,0x6667
    mult    $2,$3
    mfhi    $6
    sra $3,$6,2
    sra $4,$2,31
    subu    $2,$3,$4
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $2,4($fp)
    move    $4,$2
    sll $3,$4,2
    addu    $3,$3,$2
    sll $2,$3,1
    lw  $3,0($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    sw  $2,4($fp)
    j   $L2
$L3:
    lw  $3,4($fp)
    move    $2,$3
    j   $L1
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $fp,8($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,16
    j   $31
    .end    Reverse
    .align  2
    .globl  Palindrome
    .ent    Palindrome
Palindrome:
    .frame  $fp,32,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    sw  $fp,24($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $0,16($fp)
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal Reverse
    sw  $0,20($fp)
$L6:
    lw  $2,20($fp)
    slt $3,$2,10
    bne $3,$0,$L9
    j   $L7
$L9:
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal Reverse
    lw  $3,16($fp)
    beq $3,$2,$L10
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal Reverse
    lw  $3,16($fp)
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    sw  $2,16($fp)
$L10:
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal Reverse
    lw  $3,16($fp)
    bne $3,$2,$L8
$L11:
$L8:
    lw  $2,20($fp)
    addu    $3,$2,1
    sw  $3,20($fp)
    j   $L6
$L7:
$L5:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $fp,24($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    Palindrome
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,24,$31      # vars= 0, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,24
    sw  $31,20($sp)
    sw  $fp,16($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,24($fp)
    sw  $5,28($fp)
    jal __main
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L12
$L12:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,20($sp)
    lw  $fp,16($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,24
    j   $31
    .end    main
```